# Accessing Pingdom API with HTTParty from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, httparty, pingdom

Hi there i have a problem while accessing Pingdom API from my rails app. Here is the code:

auth = {:username => pingdom_username, :password => pingdom_password, :key => application_key }
                    response =HTTParty.get("https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.0/checks", :basic_auth => auth)

I have tried in many ways (putting the app key as a separate header, having different names :key, :app_key, :api_key) but i always receive error as a mistake with the application key:

so,

puts response.body

returns:

{"error":{"statuscode":403,"statusdesc":"Forbidden","errormessage":"Missing application key. Please see the documentation."}}

Any Ideas what am I doing Wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, there's a Pingdom API gem in Ruby. I use this repo of it since the original is a bit outdated.
https://github.com/digitalmines/pingdom-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my misstake :) THe key should be provided as an HTTP header

One way can be:

response = HTTParty.get("https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.0/checks", :basic_auth => auth, :headers => {"App-Key" => application_key})

the other way is creating a class where you set the parameters and than you call get through this class.

class Pingdom

```
include HTTParty
headers "App-Key" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxm6ogjzpd7v"
```

end

response = Pingdom.get("https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.0/checks", :basic_auth => auth)